# Wrong default_storage during tests

Tags: django, unit-testing, testing

I've a TransactionTest which tries to operate on a different default_storage:

- settings.py:

  ```
  MEDIA_ROOT='/srv/http/my_proj/media'
  ```
- tests.py:

  ```
  @override_settings(MEDIA_ROOT='/srv/http/my_proj/test')
  class OutputDataModule(TransactionTestCase):
      def test_01(self):
          myFunc()
  ```
- views.py:

  ```
  def myFunc():
      print default_storage.path('')
  ```

Why during test phase this gives to me directory **media**, instead of directory **test**?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of Django are you using?

Comment: The latest stable: 1.5.4. So, as you posted below it should be fixed...am I missing something?

Comment: Yes this bug claims to be fixed on that release. If it doesn't appear to be working then I would comment on the case. Or better yet add a regression test and fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

This was a bug in Django which appears to be fixed on the current master (1.7dev), the 1.6 pre-releases and the 1.5.X stable (1.5.4) https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/17744

Answer (score 0):

I solved using:

- tests.py

  ```
  class OutputDataModule(TransactionTestCase):
      def test_01(self):
          with self.settings(MEDIA_ROOT='/srv/http/my_proj/test'):
              myFunc()
  ```

Maybe it's a bug of the **ovverride_settings()** decorator only...